# Can Ubuntu/Samba access DFS shares on Windows Server?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, dfs

Is there a way for Ubuntu/Samba to access a DFS path on our Windows file server?

I'm primarily a Windows guy and my Ubuntu colleagues have to access the file server using regular \\server\share paths, rather than \\domain\dfsnamespace\target.

Comment: Can't really help you with this, but I found [this short tutorial](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_talk:Feisty#Mounting_DFS_shares) doing a quick Google search, just making sure you've seen it. Doesn't seem very promising but maybe it's worth a shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your Ubuntu colleagues using the CIFS client or are they using the SAMBA smbclient tool? http://pserver.samba.org/samba/ftp/cifs-cvs/linux-cifs-client-guide.pdf indicates that the smbclient tool can access DFS paths though the CIFS client cannot.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have solved this problem!!

I spent HOURS working on this before I solved, and I've documented my solution here:

http://mattslay.com/connecting-ubuntu-to-windows-shares-and-dfs-trees/

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get this to work on Ubuntu 18.04. You need to install both cifs-utils and keyutils packages. Two configuration changes also needed to be made in /etc/request-key.conf

```
create  cifs.spnego     *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k
#create dns_resolver    *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
create  dns_resolver    *       *               /sbin/key.dns_resolver %k
```

Change the deprecated `-c` parameter to `-t` for the cifs.spnego type, and (using the cifs.upcall man page recommendations) change the dns_resolver type to use /sbin/key.dns_resolver

We're also using realmd/sssd for configuring AD integration, which sets up Kerberos configuration for ssh and other tools.